# Access Point Using PfSense

Tags: router, wireless-access-point, pfsense

I am building a router that I plan to install PfSense on. I have never built a router nor used PfSense, although I have a good idea of how it works. I am going to use an ethernet controller for wired connections, but how do I configure my router to act as a wireless access point? Would a PCI network adapter work? Also, is there a way to use a high-gain antenna rather than a PCI card? Any response is appreciated; thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a PCI card as a WAP and it will come up as an Interface which you can figure. Just like the LAN & WAN interfaces.

You can, if you have a spare one, use your old ISP router. For example, out of my LAN Interface, I have it going into a Gigabit Switch with my ISP router on that switch. I just disabled DHCP on it because pfSense handles that. I can then connect my wireless devices through my old wireless router.

Or as you say, use a PCI Wireless Card and configure it when setting up pfSense. This will be fairly straight forward.

[pfSensesetup](http://pfsensesetup.com/wireless-access-point-configuration-in-pfsense/) and [pfsense documentation](https://doc.pfsense.org/index.php/Wireless_Details) are good places to look.